# how can I fix my Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-y

All of my applications are forcing to close such as its home, messaging, play store services and others.I can't make changes or even open application drawer or home.I can only open my contacts and make a call.

Comment: Is the device stock or rooted or a custom ROM? If it is stock, you will probably have to perform a factory reset. If it is a custom ROM or root, what were you doing before it happened?

Comment: i just uninstalled one application..then it automatically restarted and all of my applications are forcing to close except my contacts and call logs

Comment: What did you uninstall? And is the phone stock or rooted?

Comment: ..what do you mean rooted? i uninstalled cymera.. it's a kind of camera app

Comment: Factory reset will fix your phone for sure, there is no way of finding out what is going wrong without logs! Even with logs it is going to be hard to fix if it is the stock rom on an unrooted device.

Comment: If you don't know what being rooted is, then you probably aren't rooted. This means it is stock and would likely need a factory reset. Something likely became corrupted on the /data partition.

Comment: factory reset did't work]

Comment: factory reset didn't work

Answer (score 1):

As your device is stock, something likely became corrupted in the file system and a factory reset is about your only option. You will lose all your data, unless your phone will still communicate with a computer. If so, you may be able to use Kies to back up your data from the phone first.

To factory reset:

1. Enter recovery

   Power off the device. Press and hold the volume up key and the home button while powering up the phone. Hold these keys until the Android recovery screen appears.
2. Use your volume keys to navigate to wipe cache partition. Press the power button to choose this option. This won't destroy your data and *may* allow it to boot normally. Select reboot system with the volume keys and press power. It will reboot and hopefully work. If it doesn't, follow the next step.
3. Enter recovery mode as described above. Select "wipe data/factory reset" with the volume keys and press power to select it. THIS WILL DELETE ALL DATA FROM YOUR DEVICE. BE SURE YOU BACKED UP ANYTHING IMPORTANT. Now reboot the system and it should be back to stock with everything working again.
4. If you used kies to backup your data, now you can restore it.